# Using UDF Returned Value in Worksheet Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-udf, vba

I have created a `UDF` that returns the last populated row in a specific column. Right now, it returns the row number of the last populated row. My question is, how would I go about using this value in a worksheet function?

For example, `=COUNTBLANK("B2:B&LastRow(2))`, where `LastRow(2)` returns an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the **UDF**

```
Public Function LastRow(Rin As Range) As Long
    cl = Rin.Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

and then to use it in the worksheet:

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B2:B"& LastRow(B:B)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use VBA when you can achieve what you want with formulas?

To get the last row in a column, use this formula.

```
=MATCH(9.9E+307,A:A,1)
```

The above will give you the last row of a column A

To use it with your formula try this.

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B2:B"& MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B,1)))
```